# jsch inputstream objectoutputstream and unmarshalling

Tags: inputstream, fileinputstream, jsch, objectoutputstream

We have a scenario where we are attempting to unmarshall a java object, convert it to an inputstream and SFTP it over using JSCH API

BASICALLY -> Our goal is to coerce jSCH into pushing the object in the form of an INPUTSTREAM WITHOUT converting it into a file and then sending it over like in this example here:

```
// create a session
session = jsch.getSession(ftpUserName, ftpHost, ftpPort);
channel = session.openChannel("sftp"); 
channel.connect(); 
ChannelSftp sftpTunnel = (ChannelSftp) channel; 

// push the file you created using the channel created by the session
File f = new File(fileToTransmit); 


>> **sftpTunnel.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());**
```

Except we want to switch out that last line to use the plain-old InputStream  without an association to any file.

According to the jSCH API - NOT using a FileInputStream IS POSSIBLE:

```
void  put(InputStream src, String dst)
```

Any ideas so as to how we would go about this ?

Could we use an ObjectOutputStream ? Is there a way to take an object and unmarshall it and FEED it to an Inputstream  without EVER creating a file in the intermediate?

Thanks